# all threads hang when running a busy task in one thread

Tags: python, multithreading, linux-kernel, scheduler, gil

I have a multi-threaded python application where threads are spawned off to do various tasks. This application has been working great for months, but recently I've run into a problem.

One of the threads starts a python `subprocess.Popen` object which is running an intensive data copy command.

```
copy = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, preexec_fn = os.setsid, shell = False, close_fds = True)
if copy.wait():
  raise Exception("Unable to copy!")
```

While the copy command is running, the entire application eventually bogs down, with none of my other threads running for minutes at a time. Once `copy` finishes, everything resumes where it left off.

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent this from happening. My best theory ATM is that it has something to do with the way my kernel is scheduling processes. I added the call to `setsid()` to get the copy process scheduled separately from the main python app, but this has no effect.

I'm assuming all the `copy.wait()` function does is a `waitpid()`. Is it possible that the call takes a long time, during which that one thread holds the GIL? If so, how do I prevent/deal with this? What can I do to debug this further?

Answer (score 2):

`copy.wait()` holding the GIL was my first suspicion too. However, this doesn't appear to be the case on my system (a `wait()` call isn't preventing other threads from progressing).

You are right that `copy.wait()` eventually ends up in `os.waitpid()`. The latter looks like this on my Linux system:

```
PyDoc_STRVAR(posix_waitpid__doc__,
"waitpid(pid, options) -> (pid, status)\n\n\
Wait for completion of a given child process.");

static PyObject *
posix_waitpid(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int options;
    WAIT_TYPE status;
    WAIT_STATUS_INT(status) = 0;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, PARSE_PID "i:waitpid", &pid, &options))
        return NULL;
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    pid = waitpid(pid, &status, options);
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    if (pid == -1)
        return posix_error();

    return Py_BuildValue("Ni", PyLong_FromPid(pid), WAIT_STATUS_INT(status));
}
```

This clearly releases the GIL while it's blocked in POSIX `waitpid`.

I would try attaching `gdb` to the `python` process when it's hung to see what the threads are doing. Perhaps this would provide some ideas.

**edit** This is what a multi-threaded Python process looks like in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) info threads
  11 Thread 0x7f82c6462700 (LWP 30865)  0x00007f82c7676b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
  10 Thread 0x7f82c5c61700 (LWP 30866)  0x00007f82c7676b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
  9 Thread 0x7f82c5460700 (LWP 30867)  0x00007f82c7676b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
  8 Thread 0x7f82c4c5f700 (LWP 30868)  0x00007f82c7676b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
  7 Thread 0x7f82c445e700 (LWP 30869)  0x00000000004a3c37 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
  6 Thread 0x7f82c3c5d700 (LWP 30870)  0x00007f82c7676dcd in sem_post () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
  5 Thread 0x7f82c345c700 (LWP 30871)  0x00007f82c7676b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
  4 Thread 0x7f82c2c5b700 (LWP 30872)  0x00007f82c7676b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
  3 Thread 0x7f82c245a700 (LWP 30873)  0x00007f82c7676b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
  2 Thread 0x7f82c1c59700 (LWP 30874)  0x00007f82c7676b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
* 1 Thread 0x7f82c7a7c700 (LWP 30864)  0x00007f82c7676b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
```

Here, all threads but two are waiting for the GIL. A typical stack trace goes like this:

```
(gdb) thread 11
[Switching to thread 11 (Thread 0x7f82c6462700 (LWP 30865))] #0  0x00007f82c7676b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007f82c7676b50 in sem_wait () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000004d4498 in PyThread_acquire_lock ()
#2  0x00000000004a2f3f in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#3  0x00000000004a9671 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
...
```

You can figure out which thread is which by printing `hex(t.ident)` in your Python code, where `t` is a `threading.Thread` object. On my system, this matches up with the thread ids seen in `gdb` (`0x7f82c6462700` et al).

Comment: so, i waited until my program got stuck -- i can tell from the logs, because i stop getting debug messages. i then attempted to attach to it with gdb. this took some time, i'm guessing about the length of time that my program would "normally" be stuck for. when gdb finally got back to me, i saw all of my threads in sem_wait except for the one which was in waitpid() and one which was in clone() (this is probably my main thread, which is creating new threads).

does the preponderance of sem_wait mean everything is just waiting for the GIL?

Comment: @Igor: The first part of your comment hints at a lower-level bottleneck than Python's GIL. I'd start by examining the process and your system in `top` and `vmstat` to monitor things like memory/CPU usage, paging, I/O just before and during the time that your program fails to make progress.